# Android Speech Recognition: How to get results with highest confidence score?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am trying to develop an android application with speech recognition. Please have a look at the below code.

```
 @Override
 public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
      Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
      ArrayList<String> matches = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
      float[] scores = arg0.getFloatArray(SpeechRecognizer.CONFIDENCE_SCORES);
      receiveWhatWasHeard(matches, scores);

      //Get result with highest score
 }
```

My problem here is to get the result with *"Highest Confidence Score"*. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First element has the highest confidence score according to [specification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#RESULTS_RECOGNITION), so you can just take the first element of an array:

```
String bestResult = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION).get(0);
```

You do not need to retrieve confidence scores if you do not intend to use them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.